# How to define class name method like Integer() and when should I use it?

Tags: ruby

Some classes like `Integer` able to create a instance by

```
Integer(1) #=> 1
```

It seems the class name works as method name.
How can I create a method like this and when should I use it instead of define a `initialize` method?

Comment: If you really want to define a class method like this you can use square brackets, e.g. `def [](param) ...` then use it like this: `MyClass[param]`

Comment: @Owen Needs to be singleton, so `def self.[]()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Integer` is a `Kernel` method. In fact, it is defined as [`Kernel.Integer`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer).

You can simply create a new method that acts as initializer for your custom class:

```
class Foo
  def initialize(arg)
    @arg = arg
  end
end

def Foo(arg)
  Foo.new(arg)
end

Foo("hello")
# => #<Foo:0x007fa7140a0e20 @arg="hello">
```

However, you should avoid to pollute the main namespace with such methods. `Integer` (and a few others) exists because the `Integer` class has no initializer.

```
Integer.new(1)
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for Integer:Class
```

`Integer` can be considered a factory method: it attempts to convert the input into an Integer, and returns the most appropriate concrete class:

```
Integer(1).class
# => Fixnum
Integer(1000 ** 1000).class
# => Bignum
```

Unless you have a **real** reason to create a similar initializer, I'd just avoid it. You can easily create static methods attached to your class that converts the input into an instance.

Answer (score 3):

It’s not a class, it’s a method ([`Kernel#Integer`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer)) that begins with a capital letter.

```
def Foo(x = 1)
  "bar to the #{x}!"
end

Foo(10)  #=> "bar to the 10!"
```

It can co-exist with a constant of the same name as well:

```
module Foo; end

Foo.new  #=> #<Foo:0x007ffcdb5151f0>
Foo()    #=> "bar to the 1!"
```

Generally, though, it’s thought that creating methods that begin with a capital letter is a bad idea and confusing.